# jQuery Remove HTML element but leave the content

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a jQuery function (or just straight javascript) to turn `<span class="emphasis">15.9</span>` into `15.9`?

Basically I want to remove the `<span>` tag but leave the stuff that's inside the tag.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/ may be of some use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's called [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap). You call it on the nodes you want to unwrap, so in your case, we'd call it on `$(".emphasis").contents()`:

```
$(".emphasis").contents().unwrap();
```

Example:

```js
// Show the content of the container prior to unwrapping
console.log("before unwrapping: " + $("#container").html());

// Unwrap
$(".emphasis").contents().unwrap();

// After unwrapping
console.log("after unwrapping: " + $("#container").html());
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span class="emphasis">15.9</span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Example for when there are elements within the span:

```js
// Show the content of the container prior to unwrapping
console.log("before unwrapping: " + $("#container").html());

// Unwrap
$(".emphasis").contents().unwrap();

// After unwrapping
console.log("after unwrapping: " + $("#container").html());
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span class="emphasis"><em>15</em>.9</span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thumbs up for leaving any HTML tags after using `unwrap()`!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('span.emphasis').replaceWith($('span.emphasis').text());
```

Comment: That will work for the OP's example, but would blow away any elements within the span if there were some.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Good call.  I would need to keep tags within the `<span>` that's being taken out.  Any alternatives come to mind?

Comment: `html()` instead of `text()`

Comment: @PranavCBalan `text()` will work fine for OP's example

Comment: @PranavCBalan: Even then, you're blowing away any event handlers attached to those elements and making an unnecessry round-trip through markup.

Comment: @gtilflm: It's in my answer. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : yup, you are right... the right way is using `unwrap()` as in your answer :)

Comment: But again: For the markup in the question, this will work. It was a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
var content = document.getElementByClassName("emphasis").innerHTML;
```